# Bitcoin client from command line without blockchain

Tags: client

Any bitcoin client used on linux plateform to send bitcoin from address to another one without using blockchain or full node like bitcoind ?

Thank you

Comment: Have not same goal :)

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin transactions do not move funds from one address to another.

Bitcoin's core concept is coins. Coins are created by transactions, and can have have arbitrary value. Coins are consumed by another transaction by explicitly referring to the transaction that created them. So, in a way, transactions melt some input coins together (destroying them), and forge new ones from it (with a total value that can't exceed the value of the melted ones).

When creating a coin, you can assign it to an address (in fact a script, but let's simplify). This is just an authentication mechanism on top: in order to consume a coin assigned to address A, you have to sign the transaction with the private key corresponding to A.

So to answer your question: this is not possible. To create a transaction, you need to know the exact transactions that assigned coins to addresses of yours, and their value.

Comment: _"or full node like bitcoind"_ Perhaps it is a good idea to elaborate on the difference between a full node and a node that only holds the block headers. I think he is referring to that (but formulated it incorrectly). Other than that your answer is perfect of course. (I'll up-vote you when added)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Then there no way to do it with any software on internet ? that have her own server full node ? And any other service like blockchain.info ? because this one it's not good.

Comment: Mean her own RPC SERVER to use it with JSON RPC FROM PHP :)

Comment: @Jori: The original question asks without using the blockchain. There is no way to know the txid or amounts of transactions crediting you without watching blocks.

Comment: Oh, by 'blockchain' you meant blockchain.info?